# How do I get all the details of an Azure AD computer object?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

Calling `Get-AzureADDevice` gets me three attributes. How can I get the full list of attributes for the object? Specifically, when I use the GraphApi:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$filter=startswith(operatingSystem,'Windows')`
```

How can I achieve the same thing in Powershell?

`$aadDevices = Get-AzureADDevice -All 1` gets me the object ID, DeviceID and display name. So a filter clause on *operatingSystem* excepts.

What I am looking for is a list of all the computer objects in *AzureAD* so that I can do some automated processing.

Comment: `Get-AzureADDevice -All 1 -Filter "startswith(operatingSystem,'Windows')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-Filter "startswith(DeviceOSType,'Windows')"`, try the command as below.

```
Get-AzureADDevice -All 1 -Filter "startswith(DeviceOSType,'Windows')"
```

My test sample:

```
Get-AzureADDevice -All 0 -Top 5 -Filter "startswith(DeviceOSType,'Windows')" | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Do you know where the field name list for these kind of filter requests is stored? This because the attribute name from the GraphExplorer is different. Thanks again!

Comment: @TPL Because the command calls AAD Graph, not MS Graph, See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#device-entity

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I had known this a while ago, but then promptly forgot it. Thanks again, big help.